# Checking Between a Certain Age

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, karma-runner, project

I have an `if` statement that looks like this:

```
function isMaleBetween(value, index, array) {
        maleBetween = [];

        array.forEach(function (element) {
           if (element.active === filters.active &&
               element.gender === filters.gender &&
               element.age === filters.age.min(18) &&
               element.age === filters.age.max(30)) {
               console.log(element);
           }
        });
    }
```

This is the class where my users are. I've checked that all of the names, IDs, and filters are here:

```js
export const UserConfig = {
  test_case_1: {
    getUsers: () => UserConfig.users,
    filters: {
      active: true
    }
  },
  test_case_2: {
    getUsers: () => UserConfig.users,
    filters: {
      active: true,
      gender: 'female'
    }
  },
  test_case_3: {
    getUsers: () => UserConfig.users,
    filters: {
      active: false,
      gender: 'male',
      age: {
        min: 18,
        max: 30
      }
    }
  },
  users:[
    {
      "_id": "597c79908b3baf49d88204db",
      "age": 17,
      "name": "Mack Roach",
      "gender": "male",
      "active": false
    },
    {
      "_id": "597c799049f0cf0a330d58dd",
      "age": 22,
      "name": "Guy Howe",
      "gender": "male",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "597c79908e284bdc450a4241",
      "age": 22,
      "name": "Marie Camacho",
      "gender": "female",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "597c79906b710574bc79c970",
      "age": 21,
      "name": "Hewitt Buckley",
      "gender": "male",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "597c7990ab221a09c6671ff5",
      "age": 19,
      "name": "Jeannine Beard",
      "gender": "female",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "597c7990f807c9cb122c52ea",
      "age": 20,
      "name": "Mooney Shepard",
      "gender": "male",
      "active": false
    },
    {
      "_id": "597c7990fe0487381569b455",
      "age": 18,
      "name": "Norman Hardy",
      "gender": "male",
      "active": false
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I run this it will not loop through my array of males with a minimum of 18 years and max of 30 years. Is this statement just wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: I''m not sure what that filters object is but you may need to compare element.age with the greater than and less than comparators

Comment: Can you provide a wider context? List of objects you are iterating through.

Comment: its from another class where my users are in. 

`export const UserConfig = {
  test_case_1: {
    getUsers: () => UserConfig.users,
    filters: {
      active: true
    }
  },
  test_case_2: {
    getUsers: () => UserConfig.users,
    filters: {
      active: true,
      gender: 'female'
    }
  },
  test_case_3: {
    getUsers: () => UserConfig.users,
    filters: {
      active: false,
      gender: 'male',
      age: {
        min: 18,
        max: 30
      }
    }
  },`

Comment: but those are the filters, status and gender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling them as if they were functions. Also you need to use comparison operators.

```
element.age >= filters.age.min && element.age <= filters.age.max
```

To give them default values in case test cases don't have min or max, you can use the OR operator:

```
element.age >= (filters.age.min || 18) && element.age <= (filters.age.max || 30)
```

Comment: i will try this

Comment: @Akira please add crucial information to the question by editing it. Also, if this wasn't the problem then we need more info on `array` and `filters`

Comment: PERFECT IT WORKS THANKS it should've been obvious im new to javascript jasmine karma so this is appreciated ^_^

Comment: @Akira this actually has nothing to do with jasmine nor karma and neither do I know what those are, it's just plain Javascript, but you're welcome lol. Also I edited the answer again, if you want default values, you should use that. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

```js
let array=[ { "_id": "597c79908b3baf49d88204db", "age": 17, "name": "Mack Roach", "gender": "male", "active": false }, { "_id": "597c799049f0cf0a330d58dd", "age": 22, "name": "Guy Howe", "gender": "male", "active": true }, { "_id": "597c79908e284bdc450a4241", "age": 32, "name": "Marie Camacho", "gender": "female", "active": true }];
let filtered_array=array.filter(a=>a.age >=18 &&  a.age<=30 && a.gender==='male');

filtered_array.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log(element);
       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another perspective if you try and use declerative way of selecting the object.

```
var ge = UserConfig.users.filter((object)=> object.gender === 'male')
                         .filter((male)=> male.age >= 18 && male.age <= 30)

console.log(ge);
```

Filter through males, and then filter through their ages. The ones that made to the end, will rest in brand new list, and you can log it to see what it did.